# Can I use group_map or group_walk to iteratively export results?

Tags: r, tidyverse, contingency

I want to iteratively process a master list of comparisons using group_walk() or group_map() as an alternative method to import batches of .csv files.

I would like to input a dataset that looks like this:

| Test Assay | Var1 | Var2 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assay1 | neg | neg | 19 |
| Assay1 | neg | pos | 5 |
| Assay1 | pos | neg | 8 |
| Assay1 | pos | pos | 141 |
| Assay2 | neg | neg | 25 |
| Assay2 | neg | pos | 6 |
| Assay2 | pos | neg | 17 |
| Assay2 | pos | pos | 33 |
| Assay3 | neg | neg | 99 |
| Assay3 | neg | pos | 20 |
| Assay3 | pos | neg | 5 |
| Assay3 | pos | pos | 105 |

I want to use the function epi_analysis and export a csv for each Test Assay (in this example Assay1, Assay2, and Assay3). So far I have:

```
#Make export directory
check_create_dir <- function(the_dir) {
  if (!dir.exists(the_dir)) {
    dir.create(the_dir, recursive = TRUE) } #Creates a directory if it doesn't already exist
}

the_dir_ex <- "data_generated/epidata" #Name the new desired directory

check_create_dir(the_dir_ex) #Make the directory if it doesn't already exist

#Make function for the series of analyses
epi_analysis <- function(.x, the_dir){
  #Clean data
  dat2 <- .x  %>%
    select(c(Var1, Var2, Freq)) %>%
    pivot_wider(Var1, names_from = Var2, values_from = Freq) %>%
    remove_rownames %>% 
    column_to_rownames( var = "Var1") %>% 
    as.matrix() 
  
  #Run tests
  rval <- epi.tests(dat2, conf.level = 0.95)
  rkappa<-epi.kappa(dat2)
  gwet <- gwet.ac1.table(dat2)
  kappa2 <- kappa2.table(dat2)
  
  #Export results
  hd <- c('sensitivity', 'specificity', 'pfp', 'pfn', 'kappa', 'gwet', 'pabak')
  ests <- c(round(rval$elements$sensitivity$est, digits = 3), 
            round(rval$elements$specificity$est, digits = 3), 
            round(rval$element$pfp$est, digits = 3), 
            round(rval$element$pfn$est, digits = 3), 
            round(kappa2$coeff.val, digits = 3), 
            round(gwet$coeff.val, digits = 3), 
            round(rkappa$pabak$est, digits = 3))
  cis <- c(paste(round(rval$elements$sensitivity$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$elements$sensitivity$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","), 
           paste(round(rval$elements$specificity$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$elements$specificity$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","),
           paste(round(rval$element$pfp$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$element$pfp$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","),  
           paste(round(rval$element$pfn$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$element$pfn$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","), 
           kappa2$coeff.ci, 
           gwet$coeff.ci, 
           paste(round(rkappa$pabak$lower, digits = 3), round(rkappa$pabak$lower, digits = 3), sep = ","))
  
  df <- data.frame(hd, ests, cis)
  
  write.csv(df, 
            file = paste0(the_dir, "/", basename(.x$TestAssay)),
            na = "999.99", 
            row.names = FALSE)
  
}


#Use group_map or group_walk to iterate through the different assays in the dataset.

data <- read_csv("data_raw/EpiTest.csv") %>%
  group_by(TestAssay)%>%
  group_map(~ epi_analysis)
```

But there are no csvs in my epidata folder. Any suggestions/corrections welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your function in `group_map`. Also the function requires two arguments so pass `the_dir_ex` as well.

Use this function -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(epiR)
library(irrCAC)


epi_analysis <- function(.x, the_dir){
dat2 <- .x  %>%
  select(c(Var1, Var2, Freq)) %>%
  pivot_wider(Var1, names_from = Var2, values_from = Freq) %>%
  remove_rownames %>% 
  column_to_rownames( var = "Var1") %>% 
  as.matrix() 

#Run tests
rval <- epi.tests(dat2, conf.level = 0.95)
rkappa<-epi.kappa(dat2)
gwet <- gwet.ac1.table(dat2)
kappa2 <- kappa2.table(dat2)

#Export results
hd <- c('sensitivity', 'specificity', 'pfp', 'pfn', 'kappa', 'gwet', 'pabak')
ests <- c(round(rval$elements$sensitivity$est, digits = 3), 
          round(rval$elements$specificity$est, digits = 3), 
          round(rval$element$pfp$est, digits = 3), 
          round(rval$element$pfn$est, digits = 3), 
          round(kappa2$coeff.val, digits = 3), 
          round(gwet$coeff.val, digits = 3), 
          round(rkappa$pabak$est, digits = 3))
cis <- c(paste(round(rval$elements$sensitivity$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$elements$sensitivity$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","), 
         paste(round(rval$elements$specificity$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$elements$specificity$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","),
         paste(round(rval$element$pfp$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$element$pfp$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","),  
         paste(round(rval$element$pfn$lower, digits = 3), round(rval$element$pfn$upper, digits = 3), sep = ","), 
         kappa2$coeff.ci, 
         gwet$coeff.ci, 
         paste(round(rkappa$pabak$lower, digits = 3), round(rkappa$pabak$lower, digits = 3), sep = ","))

df <- data.frame(hd, ests, cis)

write.csv(df, 
          file = sprintf('%s/%s.csv', the_dir, .x$TestAssay[1]),
          na = "999.99", 
          row.names = FALSE)

}
```

and call it with -

```
read_csv("data_raw/EpiTest.csv") %>%
  group_by(TestAssay)%>%
  group_map(~epi_analysis(., the_dir_ex), .keep = TRUE)
```

Comment: That makes sense, but when I ran it I received this error Error in basename(.x$TestAssay) : a character vector argument expected
In addition: Warning message:
 Error in basename(.x$TestAssay) : a character vector argument expected. Do I need to fix my function?

Comment: I think so. Does your function work without `group_by` ? Try with `epi_analysis(df, the_dir_ex)`

Comment: So no, If I run `data <- read_csv("data_raw/EpiTest_subset")
epi_analysis(data, the_dir_ex)`, I get `Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"` . I think the problem lies in the clean data part of the function. I have to take each "Assay" and then make them into individual contingency table matrices. I can do this using that pipe for a single dataset, but it doesn't seem to be working well within the function

Comment: @MBell There were few changes required in the function as well as in `group_map`. I have corrected that and edited the answer. Can you try the updated answer? I tested the answer for the data you have shared and got 3 csvs as output.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Out of curiosity what was the difference between paste0 and sprintf in the function?

Comment: There is no difference. It's just that I find using `sprintf` easier.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
read_csv("data_raw/EpiTest.csv") %>%
   group_split(TestAssay) %>%
   map(~ epi_analysis(.x, the_dir_ex))
```